# Is it possible to connect 2 mouses on a raspberry pi

Tags: mouse, pygame

I want to connect 2 USB mouses on the same raspberry pi.

I want to see 2 cursors (blue and red) on the screen.

Is it possible ?

Thanks

Comment: Possible, but complicated. Since you probably mean Raspbian Linux, this may be of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4012352/linux-dual-mice-multiple-mice-with-multiple-mouse-pointers

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean mice . You can connect 2 - I do this occasionally, but you will only have 1 cursor.

Comment: i think that the plural term mice applies to rodents ... mouses is the plural of computer mouse

Comment: The English language is a funny thing. When an inanimate object is made plural, it only receives an s. Since a computer mouse is indeed an inanimate object its plural form is mouses. It is unfortunate that it has been misused for so many years.

Comment: @Wendall this was a jest - not intended to start a discussion about etymology. Now a serious issue is the plural of Pi! (NOTE I am not taking the piss)

Comment: @Milliways, how about Piae

Answer (score 0):

yes, it is possible. i have a wireless one and a built-in one to my keyboard.
i have a Rpi-4 with 4 usb ports. i use 2 of them for the keyboard and mouse connectors (and my keyboard is wireless too. same company.). but still, one cursor only.

Comment: Exactly, only one cursor, so it doesn't address the answer.